# How can I import a folder of avro files in avro-maven-plugin?

Tags: spring, maven, apache-kafka, maven-plugin, avro

I want to import multiple Avro files in a folder without specifying all Avro files, just the folder.

Current:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${avro.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>schema</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <imports>
                    <import>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro/HeaderRecord.avsc</import>
                </imports>
                <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources/avro</sourceDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                <stringType>String</stringType>
                <enableDecimalLogicalType>true</enableDecimalLogicalType>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I want something like that:

```
<imports>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro/**/*.avsc</imports>
```

Comment: Not sure what's the issue, avro plugin by default enables you to have multiple folders already inside the sourceDirectory. 
If you want avro files to be re-used between different projects I recommend that you have a separate project or module for the avro schemas and include the resulting artifact as a library in the other projects.

Answer (score 0):

take a closer look at **includes** section. hope it will help

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
<artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${avro.version}</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>profile-avro-schemas</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>schema</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/../avro/</sourceDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.avsc</include>
            </includes>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```